# CSS class not showing in iOS browsers but works in Android

Tags: css

I am writing a webpage with a facebook-style chat window. It works fine in the browser and the CSS looks like this:

```
.chatWindowContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 15%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 350px;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 20px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
        0 0px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

For mobile I want the window to span the whole bottom of the screen. I use the media query:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .chatWindowContainer {
        width: 100%;
        right: 0%;
    }
}
```

When using devtools in Chrome and using the device viewport everything is also looking fine. This also works in Chrome for Android but it does not work in Safari, Edge or Chrome for iOS, I cannot figure out why. Is there anyway I can check if I get error messages or the like?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...

I use the react package "react-speech-recognition" which uses the Web Speech API. This is NOT supported in anything but Chrome and Chrome for Android. When removing the SpeechAPI-wrapper around my WebApp the ChatWindow shows up in iOS.

So this was not a problem with CSS but rather JS.